# Read MySQL table into two-dimensional array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have a rather sticky situation:

I have been tasked with designing an application that will read the contents of a table from a MySQL database into a two-dimensional string array, scalable to 100.

The schema for the table is:

```
id = INT(11)
Username = VARCHAR(100)
Password = VARCHAR(45)
UserType = VARCHAR(10)
Full Name = VARCHAR(100)
Age = INT(11)
DOB = DATE
Location = VARCHAR(100)
Record_Created = DATETIME
```

The issue is that I cannot read this to a file and then to the application for security reasons (contains actual admin account information). Can anyone think of an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Which are the two dimensions? Can't you just have all in memory?

Comment: The application has to read from the database and pupulate the array. The application will manupulate the array first as a sort of backup, then upload it to the table when prompted

Comment: I think @Stephen is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .... into a two-dimensional string array, **scalable to 100**.

I take it that you mean the array can have up to 100 elements.

If so, then one solution is to preallocate an array of size 100 x 9, then query and read the table rows and populate the array.

A second solution is to query, read the table rows, populate a list-of-arrays, and use `List.toArray` to extract the list contents into a 2-D array.

A final solution is to use `select ... count` to find the number of rows, and use that to allocate a 2-D array with the correct size.  Then proceed as per the first solution.

---

However, using a 2-D array is a bad idea from an O-O design perspective.  Instead, you should declare a class with a field for each of the 9 columns, and then represent the table contents as an array or list of that class.

Comment: Well I feel intelligent now lol, Couldn't have asked for a better answer.

Comment: I ehrm, I don't suppose I could get an example please? Getting late in the day and my brain want's a nap =/

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following design for my above question:

```
public static String[][] Table() throws SQLException
{
    String[][] Table = null;
    table = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from usersTable";
    ResultSet rs = table.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.last();
    int rowNumb = rs.getRow();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnS = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    rs.beforeFirst();
    dbTable= new String[rowNumb][columnS];

    int i=0;
    while(rs.next() && i<rowNumb && rowNumb<100)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnS;j++)
        {
            Table[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return Table;
}
```